# Why a simple subtraction resulting in different output?

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask

I am doing a small web application project using Python Flask as back end. Everything is working fine but a small weird type of problem is occurring and am not able to figure out why this is happening.

```py
@app.route('/buy/<string:id_val>', methods=['POST','GET'])
@is_logged_in
def buy(id_val):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        buy_amt = request.form['buy_amt']
        sell_price = request.form['sell_price']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        result = cur.execute('SELECT * from company_warehouse')
        value = cur.fetchone()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM distributor_warehouse WHERE cpID=%s',[id_val])
        temp = cur.fetchone()
        if temp != None:
            cur.execute('UPDATE company_warehouse SET QTY=%s WHERE cpID=%s',(str(int(value['QTY']) - int(buy_amt)),id_val))
            cur.execute('UPDATE distributor_warehouse SET QTY=%s WHERE cpID=%s',(str(int(buy_amt)+int(temp['QTY'])),id_val))
        else:
            cur.execute('UPDATE company_warehouse SET QTY=%s WHERE cpID=%s',(str(int(value['QTY']) - int(buy_amt)),id_val))
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO distributor_warehouse(cpID,QTY,COST_PRICE,SELL_PRICE) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)',(id_val,buy_amt,value['PRICE_PER_UNIT'],sell_price))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        flash('Buyed Successfully','success')
        return redirect(url_for('buy_product'))
        cur.close()
    return render_template('buy_product.html')
```

This is my **app.py** and the problem is occurring in `str(int(value['QTY']) - int(buy_amt))` of the `UPDATE` statement .

[This is the output which am getting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH5IWWCujpY&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always fetching the first row from company_warehouse irrespective of the id_val that you receive as parameter.  By changing that, the quantity will get updated properly.

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM company_warehouse WHERE cpID=%s',[id_val]) 
value = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: now i got it why only the 1st row was giving correct answer.